# Permission denied even with sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, digital-ocean

Following this tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

and trying to use the command

```
echo 'prefix=/usr/local' > node/etc/npmrc
```

however I get a permission denied error, even when using sudo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

```
echo 'prefix=/usr/local' > node/etc/npmrc
```

> however I get a permission denied error, even when using sudo.

You haven't shown us the failing command using `sudo`. Please update your question and show us the exact command that failed, along with the exact error message.

Meanwhile, I can guess that the failing command was:

```
sudo echo 'prefix=/usr/local' > node/etc/npmrc
```

That runs the `echo` command with root privileges (which is not particularly useful, since you can run`echo` as an ordinary user).  The redirection is handled by your current shell process, and is subject to the permissions of the current user.

Since `>` is handled by the shell, you need a shell running as `root` to handle it:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'prefix=/usr/local' > node/etc/npmrc"
```

Comment: `| sudo tee` is another common way.